# How to use apply as a row-wise unpacking of 2 variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with many more rows than columns, comprised of locations.  I created a function to calculate x,y locations, call it "findLoc". When I use apply to calculate all x0,y0 locations, I want df.apply to add them in row 1, then row 2 then row 3. In my case it is adding them to column 1, column 2 etc.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def findLoc(x0,y0):
    x0 = 1
    y0 = 2
    return x0,y0

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2, 4)))
df.columns= ['x0','y0','x1','y1']
df.index= ['Locations A','Locations B']

print(df)

df2=df.copy()

df2['x0'],df2['y0'] = df.apply(lambda loc : findLoc(loc['x0'],loc['y0']), axis=1)

df2
```

I have looked at several tutorials about how apply/applymap/map work but it still eludes me.

My data frame begins empty, looking like:

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

After my code runs, it looks like:

1 1 0 0

2 2 0 0

I want it to be

1 2 0 0

1 2 0 0

In reality I really want it to be

1 2 0 0

1 2 0 0

1 2 0 0

1 2 0 0

1 2 0 0

Or longer, but I get an error when I have more rows than variables.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

EDIT:

The way I got around it was to break df.apply into two calls, where one was the x and one was the y. But this is redundant and would like to not have ot run the same routine twice just to make it work.

for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def findLoc_x(x0,y0):
    x0 = 1
    y0 = 2
    return x0

def findLoc_y(x0,y0):
    x0 = 1
    y0 = 2
    return y0

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2, 4)))
df.columns= ['x0','y0','x1','y1']
df.index= ['Locations A','Locations B']

print(df)

df2=df.copy()

df2['x0'] = df.apply(lambda loc : findLoc_x(loc['x0'],loc['y0']), axis=1)
df2['y0'] = df.apply(lambda loc : findLoc_y(loc['x0'],loc['y0']), axis=1)

# df2['x0'],df2['y0'] = findLoc(df['x0'],df['y0'])

df2
```

This code works as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

`axis = 1` in `df.apply()` means you are applying that function column wise.
This results in the columns `df2['x0']`, `df2['y0']` becoming `1,2` as returned by `findLoc`, which should result in:

```
1 1 0 0
2 2 0 0
```

One way you can go is:

```
df2['x0'],df2['y0'] = findLoc(.. , ..)
```

which will result in

```
1 2 0 0
1 2 0 0
```

because the value of `findLoc(a,b) = (1,2)` is assigned to `df2['x0']` and `df2['y0']`.
I don't get why you need to use df.apply, if there is any purpose, please comment in the answer.

Comment: Samarth Bhatia, this is a much more simplified script than what I am applying it to

Comment: When I remove axis=1, I get: KeyError: 'x0'

Comment: Yes, that is because x0 is not an index, it is a column name and can only be used with axis=1.

Comment: Hmm, I see that it is quite simplified. I will try to find something.

Comment: Should I be using map or applymap in this instance isntead?

Comment: Samarth, I just edited the post with some info that may help.